# Фраза "Я сделал это"

Tags: нормы-языка

Здравствуйте! Возник спор с одним товарищем насчет использования это фразы. Я знаю, фраза некорректна, пришла к нам от кривых переводчиков, но доказать каким-либо правилом (нормой) русского языка не могу. Не могли бы вы мне с этим помочь?

Answer (score 2):

Тут есть небольшая инверсия ( нейтральный вариант - *Я это сделал*), но никаких нарушений норм русского литературного языка, я здесь не вижу.

Comment: Нет-нет, именно вот так - Я сделал это, мы сделали это и так далее. 

Я уточню - почему принято отвечать, например:

- Ты помыл посуду?
- Да.

Или

- Помыл.

Но не:

- Ты помыл посуду?
- Я сделал это.
Или:

- Я это сделал.

Как-то идиотски выглядит, не находите?

Comment: Корректность фразы зависит от контекста. Если вас 20 раз спрашивают, помыли ли вы посуду, вполне уместно ответить развернуто, чтобы дошло. А вообще порядок слов некорректный - логическое ударение падает на "это". Варианты: я это сделал, я уже сделал это, я таки сделал это. Однако получившее распространение в устной речи "Я сделал это!" (как констатация достижения) повлияло и на восприятие фразы на письме. Она узнаваема и всегда воспринимается как возглас победителя.

Comment: Для возгласа победителя порядок слов как раз очень корректный: я сдЕлал это! Перестановка тонического ударения позволяет слово "сделал" сделать центром фразы.

Comment: У  меня  ощущение,  что  это  заимствованное  выражение.

Comment: У Фрэнка Синатры есть песня  "I Did It My Way": To think I did all that - Подумать только! Я сделал всё это!

Comment: >Корректность фразы зависит от контекста.  
  
Грамматическая - нет.  
А стилистика тут, вроде, не рассматривается.

Comment: Сама фраза корректна, и такое сочетание используется давно. Статистически да, английский прототип является устойчивой фразой, а в русском сочетание не является (пока?) ходовым выражением. Поэтому когда используется часто, то и звучит как калька: обычно ведь оно означает ровно то, что сказано ("я сделал стол", "я приготовил это", "я допустил это", "я сделал это") без всяких намёков на успех и скрытых смыслов. А насколько это "красиво" звучит — уже другой вопрос.

Comment: Проблема в отличии устной речи от письменной. В разговоре можно акцентировать любое из трех слов. А на письме ударная позиция в конце предложения. "Я сделал ЭТО" - в первый раз читается только так. Потом, прочитав контекст и подумав, можно сделать вывод, что "я СДЕЛАЛ это". Но такие фразы считаются стилистически дефектными. Вопрос в том, почему в языке не закрепилось как сигнал победы "я это сделал". Закрепилась калька с воспроизведением интонации оригинала.

Comment: Эта фраза без контекста не имеет смысла и прочитывается  только в соответствии с предыдущим содержанием, например: "Ты какое задание сделал - то или это?" - "Я сделал это". И никаких восклицаний, и никакого акцентирования. А в форме "девиза победителя"  логически выделяется слово "сделал", и именно ИНВЕРСИЯ  тонического ударения с конца фразы на середину обеспечивает это акцентирование.

Answer (score 2):

Я сдЕлал это! - девиз человека, добившегося успеха в каком-либо деле (логическое ударение на слове "сделал").

Значение примерно такое: "Это было очень трудно, но я всё-таки сделал это. Я горжусь собой".

Comment: Правильно.  Можно  и  сказать  и  понять.  Но  раньше  так  не  говорили.  Фраза  правильная,  но  с  акцентом.

Comment: А как сказать коротко и по-русски? Фразой пользуются, потому что нет подходящего эквивалента, а необычная грамматика "с акцентом" кажется выразительной, несущей подходящую  энергетику для выражения чувств.

Comment: >@София - А как сказать коротко и по-русски?

**Сделано!** В русской культурной традиции не принято выпячивать свои достижения, поэтому для подобных утверждений чаще всего используется  безличная форма - *Сказано - сделано*.

Comment: В определенной среде также говорят "пацан сказал — пацан сделал!" Но это совсем другой смысл, а именно: я не  бросаю слов на ветер, я отвечаю за свои слова.

Comment: У "Сказано - сделано" естественно смысл другой, я лишь привёл поговорку в пример. Фраза с пацаном тоже в этом смысле показательна, так как она может применяться и по отношению к себе. То есть, даже в это среде своё участие на уровне языка прикрывается 3-м лицом, а не "Я сказал - я сделал"

По-русски, тем же смыслом, что и "Я сделал это" будет обладать фраза "Сделано!" или более конкретная безличная форма. У нас "Я - последняя буква алфавита", а скромность - одна из высших добродетелей. Но это всё на уровне культурологии, на уровне чистой грамматики фраза построена верно.

Comment: >> А как сказать коротко и по-русски? Фразой пользуются, потому что нет подходящего эквивалента, а необычная грамматика "с акцентом" кажется выразительной, несущей подходящую энергетику для выражения чувств.

Да, если это не на каждом шагу.
Нет эквивалента... Так рассуждать, так и у "о'кей" нет эквивалента. И у "вау!" тоже нет эквивалента.
Мы переплыли! Мы построили! Мы, в конце концов, выиграли. И так далее. Нет в русском на "делать" такой нагрузки, как в английском.
Жаль нельзя спросить у Норы Галь, впрочем, книжку можно почитать, может, там и есть про это. Даже думаю, что есть.

Answer (score 2):

Это калька с английского. Пришла в последние 15-20 лет, и да, от кривых переводчиков. Как прикажете переводить поток хлынувших голливудских фильмов? Мучиться над каждой фразой по часу? - ничего не заработаешь. Так что переводчиков понять можно.

А по-русски так не говорят.

Еще более вопиющий пример: "ОНИ убили его" вместо правильного "его убили".

Answer (score 0):

Одна и та же фраза может быть корректна в одной ситуации и некорректна - в другой. В втором     диалоге, на вопрос "Ты помыл посуду?" ,действительно,отвечать "  Я сделал это" - некорректно. Однако в другой ситуации , такая фраза приемлема.

Answer (score 0):

> Я знаю, фраза некорректна, пришла к нам от кривых переводчиков,

Фраза вполне корректна, а переводчики не кривые.
We do it  / We've done it (и подобные) так и надо переводить.